# Does hadoop cache hdfs-block for non-local-mappers?

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Let's say I have mapper-task running on DN1.  The hdfs-block I'm interested in is on DN2.  It is my understanding that hadoop will NOT cache the block on DN1.  Meaning that If I'm reading records of 1MB, and the block is 512 MB, then I'll go over the network 512 times.  Is this correct?

---

Maybe my question is not worded correctly.  I know about data-locality, my question is about the times when data-locality is not possible.  If there is 512 MB of data sitting in a block on DN2 but the mapper is running on DN1 and each record served by the record-reader is 1MB, does that mean that we're going over the network 512 times?  Or does hadoop cache the block - meaning does it copy the 512 MB block from DN2 to DN1 and then starts servicing the record-reader.  I think that it doesn't cache...I think it goes over the network 512 times and grabs the information record-by-record.

Answer (score 0):

One of the Hadoop cumber stones is 'data locality'. First data processing(mappers) will run on the nodes where data physically exisits. An exemption is when mapper process the last 'row' of the block, this row can be split into a block in other node, in such case data will be copied to the mapper that started processing.

Comment: clearly, the data for the record needs to be copied.  But does that mean the entire block is copied?  I'm thinking not.  Also, this scenario occurs when the file input format is not splittable.

Comment: In case of on splittable data, every thing will be copied to the mapper. In real case first part of file will be(512mb) on DN1 and second 1MB on DN2. Naturally Mapper on DN1 should do the processing.